# What is the best AntiVirus application available for non-technical users?

Tags: software-recommendation, viruses, malware, antivirus

I am looking for an AntiVirus for Ubuntu, and have researched potential products. I do not want a paid product, but i do want a user friendly interface.

**I do not want rants about how unnecessary it is on Ubuntu.**

My considerations are:

- [avast! Linux Home Edition](http://www.avast.com/linux-home-edition#tab4) (Free with Registration, 27.7MB)
- [AVG Anti-Virus Free Edition For Linux](http://free.avg.com/gb-en/download.prd-alf) (Free, 138MB)
- [Avira AntiVir Personal](http://www.avira.com/en/support-download-free-antivirus) (Free, 54.46MB)
- [Bitdefender for Unices](http://www.bitdefender.co.uk/business/antivirus-for-unices.html) (Free with Registration, 27.7MB)
- [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/) (Open-Source, Free, 45.8MB)

My concerns are:

1. Ease of Scan
2. Ease of Update
3. Ease of Schedule
4. Detection Rates

Which, if any, come with good GUIs?

Note: I am willing to do complicated setup, so long as my great aunt can use it.

Comment: ...and what do you want it to do!? Most important question... since virusscanning mosttimes is scanning mails for Windows system. And if it is your aunt I'd advice learning her how to use gmail :)

Comment: You should mention if you are going to scan the Ubuntu system or some windows file systems that happen to connect to the Ubuntu computer. The fact that Ubuntu has some Anti virus solutions does not mean that you will find viruses in it. This are there to be used to scan Windows systems that connect to Ubuntu (Hard drives, network, flash drives..) or to Mail systems that use/have Windows files. So just remember that before starting to think that Ubuntu has some weird super virus.

Comment: Your first link (to avast!) points to AVG.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Fixed the links (someone fixed the first two and broke the second two) and added bitdefender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

avast! Linux Home Edition ofc! Simple the best interface and virus detection available for a home user.

But, I have to agree on the comments, if you are not running a server an AV is a bit overkill for linux. On servers were files are hosted for users, using different operative systems, etc and AV can detect and eliminate virus for the user, for home linux installations? Not really something you need a lot.

Don't forget that most these AV for home users are not licensed for server use or even organizations so be careful with that.

Comment: I am looking more at shipping to home use pre-installed. I am aware i'd have to talk to practically any software manufacturer about that.

Comment: The thing with avast is that you need an email to register, but allows use for 30 days non registered. Maybe an automatic installation can be triggered upon first boot for that (script). The rest should be ok since its the final user that is the responsible for the registration.

Comment: Again, so long as it's simple to use once it's done. I had nothing but trouble with updating ClamAV last time, but i can test that before shipping.

Comment: I'll do that on a vbox tonight, if I enconter any issues with it ill let you know (last time I tried was a bit of time ago). Anyways, gl. Hope it fits your needs.

Comment: Accepted Answer: Provides the simplest GUI for Updating and Scanning. ClamTK is a similar GUI for ClamAV, but is difficult to get to show up-to-date for all three areas, whereas avast! is one button. Dislike BitDefender because it doesn't play at all with the theme. Disappointed AVG doesn't have any interface, loved it on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There is also BitDefender Antivirus Scanner which is a free download.
It keeps out of the way until you need it or you can set it to run in the background as in windows.

http://www.bitdefender.co.uk/business/antivirus-for-unices.html

Once on this page there is a link on the left hand side to 'Request a Free License
(for personal use only)'

Get it from [here](http://download.bitdefender.com/SMB/Workstation_Security_and_Management/BitDefender_Antivirus_Scanner_for_Unices/Unix/Current/EN_FR_BR_RO/Linux/).

Comment: I'd checked BitDefender, but thought it was a pay only programme, due to the Buy License bit on the right of that first page. What's the interface like?

Comment: I presume i should download BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.6-4.linux-gcc4x.i586.deb.run and run in Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Subjective question, but I would add ClamAV to plus ones.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware and http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/free-linux-antivirus-programs/

I personally believe AV is needed because I use thumb drives for work (Windows system) so I could easily transfer virus's to my system and I also like to torrent on my machine so I'm wide open to virus download. Check out the wikipedia link it gives a list of all the linux AV software out there to check out for your self and decide what works best for you.