# How To Open Windows Antivirus in ubuntu

Tags: windows-xp, antivirus

I have Dual Boot Windows xp and Ubuntu . I have Net Protector Antivirus in Windows but I can't open it in ubuntu through Wine. Please give me solution.
  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best AntiVirus application available for non-technical users?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71010/what-is-the-best-antivirus-application-available-for-non-technical-users) and for additional information see also [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to install clamav, which is in the repositories and is FLOSS. We use it at work for scanning mail in a multiplatform environment. You could also use bitdefender which works good on ubuntu, if this is a non-commercial use pc.
Generally antivirus software will not be of much help against threats against gnu/linux. I understand however that you want to protect your windows installation from sideloading viruses.